# Golang detect system interrupt

Tags: go

I wrote an utility to batch delete files as followed

```
        stdinScanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
        fileScanner := bufio.NewScanner(inFile)
        for fileScanner.Scan() {
            target := strings.TrimSpace(fileScanner.Text())
            if len(target) > 0 {
                printUtf16("Delete %s?\n", target)
                stdinScanner.Scan()
                if len(stdinScanner.Text()) > 0 {
                    fmt.Println("Non empty return not allowed")
                    os.Exit(1)
                } else {
                    // TROUBLE: Had to sleep here or interrupt does not work
                    time.Sleep(100 * time.Millisecond)
                    e := os.Remove(target)
                    if e != nil {
                        panic(e)
                    }
                    printUtf16("%s deleted\n", target)
                }
            }
        }
```

I have an **inFile** that specifies a list of files I want to delete. For every file to delete, I prompt myself just to be sure. Only if I enter empty output would the program delete the file and proceed to the next file.

Now note the very ugly **time.Sleep** in this middle of the code. I have noticed that if I did not insert that **time.Sleep** the application behaves unexpectedly when I press **ctrl+c**. Seems like after **ctrl+c** is pressed **stdinScanner.Scan()** would return false and no error and **stdinScanner.Text()** would be empty just as I expected when an empty input is entered. The file that I was prompted for would be deleted before the application is interrupted and quits.

I have noticed that adding this **time.Sleep** allows the application **more than sufficient** time to exit and prevent the current file to be deleted. However I really dislike this solution. Just asking if there is a function I can call instead of the **time.Sleep** to check if the application is currently processing a keyboard interrupt and if so we don't delete the current file?

Comment: This might be a terminology problem. A thing called "keyboard interrupt" exists but keyboard interrupts are not handled by your application and Ctrl-C is not delivered to your application as a "keyboard interrupt" but as a os.Signal (in Go speak) which you can trap via os/signal.Notify (You'll find plenty of examples).

Comment: The loop continues after stdin is closed.  Fix by breaking from the loop when stdinScanner.Scan() returns false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Volker and Cerise for the response
The answer turns out is quite simple. Can't believe I overlooked it. We just need to check scanner's return and err before proceeding

```
scanResult := stdinScanner.Scan()
scanError := stdinScanner.Err()
if scanResult && scanError == nil {
    if len(stdinScanner.Text()) > 0 {
        fmt.Println("Non empty return not allowed")
        os.Exit(1)
    } else {
        deleteFunc(target)
    }
} else {
    errString := "None"
    if scanError != nil {
        errString = scanError.Error()
    }
    fmt.Printf("Scanner returns %t, err: %s\n", scanResult, errString)
    os.Exit(1)
}
```